# Why do strings get printed twice when using printf in C?

Tags: c, printf

My program asks the user to provide a *string*, which will be copied into an array of characters. Then, with a `for` loop, the program simply copies the elements of the first array into the second array.

```
int main() {

    int i;
    char string1[4], string2[4];

    // Get the first string
    printf("Insert your string: ");
    scanf("%s", string1);

    // Copy the values into the second array
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        string2[i] = string1[i];
    }

    // Print the second string
    printf("%s", string2);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I print the *string* using the `printf()` function the *string* gets printed twice.

Let's say I input the word

> bars

The output will be

> barsbars

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char string1[4], string2[4];
```

4-element char array is not enough for 4-character strings. You need one more for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 4):

> *Why?*

**TL;DR** answer: [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To explain, the problem here, with an input array defined like `string1[4]`, (4 elements only), an input string like `bars` will be overruning the allocated memory region (in attempt to store the terminating `\0`), which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should always take care of your input buffer length, like for an input array of `string1[4]`, your `scanf()` should look like

```
scanf("%3s", string1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char bString []= {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};               
printf("bString:%s\n", bString);
```

Output:

> bString:stringstring

Solution: Always include the terminating character

```
char bString []= {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

Or simply write:

```
char bString [] = "string";
```